# Notation package: StringMemberQ in conditional notation definition

Tags: pattern-matching, custom-notation, notation

Suppose that I have a list, allSpecies, that contain a set of symbols, each of which has been assigned a new notation using Notation[...]. As an example, the internal representation is C60s, and the display form is C<sub>60</sub><sup>*</sup> (but with the * back against the C -- not sure how to do that on StackExchange).

I now want to define a new Notation for single-parameter functions of any of the symbols that are in allSpecies. So C<sub>60</sub><sup>*</sup> [t] (for any t) could be entered as and would be displayed as [C<sub>60</sub><sup>*</sup>]<sub>t</sub>. Critically, I only want this alternate functional notation if the symbol is in allSpecies.

I have tried to accomplish this following [the model shown here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Notation/tutorial/ComplexPatternsAndAdvancedFeatures.html#259282198). So I defined:

```
StringMemberQ[any___]:=MemberQ[ToExpression[any]
```

And I then used the Notation palette to add a Notation entry. The left-hand side became [stuff1]<sub>t_</sub> and the right-hand side became stuff2[t_], where the two "stuff" parts I began with InsertPatternWrapper from the palette, and Stuff1 was a_/;StringMemberQ[a,allSpecies], and Stuff2 was a_/;MemberQ[a,allSpecies]. But it doesn't work. Here is the expanded version of the code:

```
Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper[
SubscriptBox[
RowBox[{"[", TemplateBox[{RowBox[{"a_", "/;", 
RowBox[{"StringMemberQ", "[", 
RowBox[{"a", ",", "allSpecies"}], "]"}]}]}, 
"NotationPatternTag"], "]"}], "t_"]] 
\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] 
ParsedBoxWrapper[
RowBox[{
TemplateBox[{
RowBox[{"a_", "/;", 
RowBox[{"MemberQ", "[", 
RowBox[{"a", ",", "allSpecies"}], "]"}]}]}, 
"NotationPatternTag"], "[", "t_", "]"}]]]
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to make it work.

```
MakeSpecies[f_] := With[{n = ToString[f,StandardForm]}, 
     Notation[ParsedBoxWrapper@SubscriptBox[RowBox[{"[", n, "]"}], "t_"]
     \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]
     ParsedBoxWrapper@RowBox[{n, "[", "t_", "]"}]]]
```

And then I just call it for each of the species that I want to behave this way.